# replace '_blank' in javascript window.open links with '_self'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a small chrome extension that will replaces the target in javascript window.open links but not sure how to approach.

this is an example link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank','toolbar=1,location=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'));">
```

Here I want to replace '_blank' with '_self' instead so all these links open in the same tab.

Edit: just noticed some of the links has __blank or _new so need to replace other variations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with **all** `<a>` tags, you can use a for loop:

```js
for (let link of document.querySelectorAll("a")) { // Note: for/of was recently introduced
  link.href = link.href.replace("_blank", "_self");
};
```

Comment: [https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_for_of](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_for_of)

Comment: if there's other variation of _blank like _new or __blank could I make an array with all variations and run a replacement through all links?

Comment: I would personally just modify it so it replaces them in the same loop: `link.href = link.href.replace("__blank", "_self").replace("_blank", "_self").replace("_new", "_self");`